# libgcrypt and rdrand usage

Tags: randomness, entropy

For some reasons, I was looking into libgcrypt source code and found [this](https://github.com/gpg/libgcrypt/blob/b64b029318e7d0b66123015146614118f466a7a9/random/rndlinux.c#L189).

If I understand this correctly, while asking to use /dev/random for some bytes, it actually checks first if rdrand is available (without being very explicit about it) and uses it up to 25%, which is fine I guess if it was used standalone.

Where I find it a little tricky is that it is activated by default. Also doesn't /dev/random rely on rdrand as well? Thus increasing the real % of entropy coming out of the Intel/AMD rdrand?

Isn't this a bit too much relying on rdrand closed implementation?

Comment: Latest kernels use RDRAND can add into the entropy pool, they don't use it directly.  See https://lwn.net/Articles/760584/  The precise behavior depends on what kernel you're using and how it was built.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that this landed on the right site after migration. Reviewing implementations in code is not really what this site is about; I think that there is more expertise on a Q/A site for a specific platform (as Swashbuckler indicated, it depends on the runtime).